# add vertical scrollbar to cakephp3

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp3 I have a lot of data to display like 100 rows. I want the data to appear in a scrollbox so it displays only 10 rows at a time but you can scroll down and see the rest of the data. I dont want pagination for this as a solution. I couldnt find an example for this

Below is the code to display the data and I want to add this data with scrollbars

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th> Name</th>
          <th> Email</th>
          <th>Select</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php foreach ($resumes as $key => $resume) { ?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $resume['id'] ?></td>
         <td><?= $resume['first_name'] .' '. $resume['last_name']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
         <td><?php echo $resume['email']//.'<br> '. $resume['mobile']; ?></td>


?>
```

........

Comment: What exactly do you  need to better understand this question? If I cant find the answer then maybe it would be more constructive to show some effort in a response instead of a downvote. I just started here so this really comes across as trolling!

Comment: This maybe help you: [http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/)

Answer (score 0):

just put your table in a div and make that div have a fixed height and overflow-y property. and in your tables i suggest you use the cake way `$this->Html->tableHeaders` and `$this->Html->tableCells`